# Annotation of the class is loaded in web server is com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, annotations, jersey

I have a problem with the annotation of the class is loaded in web server(using maven and jersey) . When i got the annotation of the loaded class, the type of annotation is **com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52** and i cannot cast to our defined type. But if i loaded that class in a normal java project, the type of annotation is our defined type.

code loaded class:

```
 URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{Paths.get("C:\\HelloWorld.jar").toUri().toURL()});
 addURLToSystemClassLoader(new URL("file:///C:/HelloWorld.jar"));

Class c = cl.loadClass("NewHelloWorldPackage1.Doc_NewDocument1");
Annotation[] aaaa = c.getAnnotations(); // the type of each annotation in aaaa is com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52
```

and the class to load:

```
import a.b.OtxElement;

@OtxElement((a.b.OtxElementTypes.Otx))
public class Doc_NewDocument1 {
  //something to do here...
}
```

Please tell me what is the difference? I need to get our defined type.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you get a proxy in front of your annotation type should not matter. It might actually mislead you into believing that this is the cause for problems you are having. If stuff like "isAnnotationPresent(..)" fails, it is not due to that proxy, it is because you have loaded the annotation class multiple times using multiple classloaders. For example, Jetty gives priority to the WebApp classloader by default. So if your Jetty server instance (or Tomcat or whatever) already has loaded the annotation class, and the annotation is on your WebApp's classpath, too, you can have problems like "getAnnotation()" not returning anything. Just make sure that the library containing your annotation is not loaded twice.